# Embedded objects in Mongoid are changing ids when updated from Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, mongoid, ember-data

I have two models in Mongoid: Teams and Players where Players are embedded in Teams.

On the front end we use `Ember.js` and every time I add a new Player to a team I save the parent record (ie. the Team). Every time I update the parent record on the backend in rails I call:

`Team.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(params[:team])`

Now the problem is each time I call `update_attributes` all the embedded objects (ie the players) get recreated with new ids and saved in the team. This is unexpected since I would expect all the old records to continue to persist with the same ids and a new record to be added to the document.

How do I keep the same ids for the old records?

Comment: What does `params[:team]` look like?

Comment: It looks something like this: `{"name"=>"Team A", "players"=>[{"name"=>"Old Player", "team_id"=>"52e9918ff15aeb5928000083", "id"=>"5302c75cc5c55f60ef000006"}, {"name"=>"P2", "team_id"=>"52e9918ff15aeb5928000083", "id"=>nil}]}`. I realized I was getting the following warning recently: "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id". I tried to set attr_accessible for id, and that solved my problem in that it wouldn't recreate records with different ids, but it also wouldn't assign ids to new records altogether since the incoming params had an id of nil for new records.

Comment: How is `Team` configured? Any `accepts_nested_attributes_for` stuff in there?

Comment: I experimented with that, I put in in `accepted_nested_attributes_for :players` but it gave me the same problem. Right now in Team I have an `embeds_many :players` and a `belongs_to :league` and `belongs_to :tenant`. I'm also scoping everything by tenant id

Comment: The way I'm currently solving this is by setting `attr_accessible :id` and then in the controller, before I call the `update_attributes` method I go through all the embedded records in the `params` hash and assign ids to the ones with `"id" => nil`. I'm hoping there is a more robust way to solve this

Comment: `attr_accessible :id` is the wrong approach. I think you need the nested attributes stuff back and then transform your `players` to look like `{ '0' => { ... }, '1' => { ... }, ... }`, that's pretty much what I ended up doing.

Comment: Can you give me a quick explanation of why `attr_accessible :id` is the wrong approach?

Comment: Because changing an object's identity when you're not really changing anything is bizarre? Read the [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html) and they will tell you what nested attributes should look like.